# Code to insert button works but get 438 error when add background color to button

Tags: excel, button, vba

The code to insert the button works fine, but I get the `error 438` when I try to add background color to the button

```
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

I have tried variations of this but I am not getting it

Thanks

```
Sub CreateButton()
Dim Obj As Object
Dim Code As String


Sheets(1).Select

'create button
Set Obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=35)
Obj.Name = "CommandButton1"
'buttonn text
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption = "Test Button"
'button color
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

'macro text
Code = "Sub CommandButton1_Click()" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "Call Tester" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "End Sub"
'add macro at the end of the sheet module
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(1).CodeName).CodeModule
    .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
End With
End Sub

Sub Tester()
MsgBox "You have click on the test button"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the `Object` object of the `OleObject`. I know it sounds a bit redundant so see the simplified code below and let me know if you need added help.

```
Sub GiveItAWhirl()
    Dim oCmd As OLEObject

    Set oCmd = Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100)
    oCmd.Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Thank you` I had put hrs playing and searching for that, glade I finally asked